# В input поменять стиль в focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Подскажите, как при фокусе на input убрать прямой слеш и изменения цвета шрифта на чёрный (при помощи jquery). Тоесть при нажатии ничего не должно меняться.
Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополню. Нужно без вызова события при нажатии на INPUT. Нужно сразу при генерации такой формы прописать css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже знать не хочу зачем нужно убирать курсор ввода, но можно хакнуть систему: скрыть текст (и курсор), но включить только тексту тень в виде очертаний:

```css
#t {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 lightgray;
  cursor: default;
}
#t:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='t' value='Test' />
```

Вряд ли это хорошее UI/UX.